# multiple checkboxes submit url generator php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes in my form and i want to use those to generate the url.
An example :

```
  <form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="a">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="c">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="d">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

When the user presses the submit button he will have to be redirect to the generated url created as followed :

> www.domain.com/checkbox/a+b+c+d

Depending on the choises of the user the url should be generated as above.
How can i pull this of?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a php example if you don't want to use AJAX

Top of your checkbox.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
       $url = 'checkbox/' . implode('+',$_POST['checkbox']);

       header('Location:'. $url);
       die;    
    }


?>
```

Comment: your a hero! worked like a charm!! thx a lot, you made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

In your checkbox.php, get all the checked checkboxes, create the url you want, and redirect the user to it with `header("Location: $url")`.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="a" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="b" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="c" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="d" />
```

checkbox.php:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
  $url = "http://www.domain.com/checkbox/";
  $params = '';
  $checkBoxes = $_POST['checkbox'];
  foreach ($checkBoxes as $value) {
    $params .= $value;
    if ($value != $checkBoxes[count(checkBoxes) - 1])
      $params .= '+';
  }
  $url .= $params;
}

header("Location: $url");
```